# I want to return to "input" after type wrong character in python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I want to return to the "input" after the user type another character that is not "n" string,
The entry data is a "Input" that make the user press enter to continue or type "n", but if the user type another string, the console close

```
_WriteList = input("Write a textfile with the file list? (Enter) Yes or (n) No: ")

if bool(_WriteList) == False:
    sevenZipListWrite()
elif _WriteList == "n":
    sevenZipList()
```

Comment: Please try to do some research before you post the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it using a while loop like this

```
_WriteList = input("Write a textfile with the file list? (Enter) Yes or (n) No: ")

while _WriteList != 'n':
  sevenZipListWrite()
  _WriteList = input("Write a textfile with the file list? (Enter) Yes or (n) No: ")

sevenZipList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while-loop:

```
>>> user_input = ''
>>> while user_input != 'n':
...     user_input = input("Enter your input: ")
...
Enter your input: a
Enter your input: 1
Enter your input: 3
Enter your input: n
>>>
```